# Не могу включить ASP.NET Core 3 preview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core

Как заставить VS 2019 использовать предварительные версии, когда включена опция use previews of the .net core sdk? Нужны стандартные шаблоны (предварительной версии) при создании проекта.

VS 2019 RC не интересует. При создании проекта на WPF .Net Core происходит ошибка, хотя в настройках проекта версия .NET Core меняется без проблем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: NET Core 3.0 should be used with the latest previews of Visual Studio. - вам придется поставить студию 16.3, из превью канала.

Answer (score 0):

не заметил, что на странице загрузки написано для VS 2019 16.2 доступен только v3.0.0-preview6, preview7 уже для 16.3+, но на деле preview7 работает и в 16.2+